# How to place textfield position using tap gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextfield

```
super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("hideKeyboard"))
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = true

    scrlView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    //self.navigationController!.navigationBarHidden = true

     scrlView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(UIScreen .mainScreen().bounds.size.width, (regButton.frame.size.height + regButton.frame.origin.y)+20)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func hideKeyboard() {
    scrlView.endEditing(true)
    scrlView .setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: true)
}


@IBAction func tapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    scrlView.endEditing(true)
    scrlView .setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: true)
}
```

My hideKeyboard function is ok. But now I want to cahnge the position of the textfields above the keyboard when I tap on them.

Comment: what exactly you need means when textfield begin editing then it should scroll up ??

Comment: Exactly.. @Shubhambairagi

Comment: then what you need to do is set the delegate  `textFieldShouldReturn` . here set contant offset for scrollview . and on the tapGausture Reset it again. see my ans below

Comment: Where is the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    scrl.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0.0, textField.center.y-120), animated: true)
}
```

And your `func hideKeyboard()` should be remain same
Hope it will helpful for u

Comment: you can set  `ContentOffset` According to your requirement

Comment: func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        
        
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        scrlView .setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: true)
        
        return true
    }
I have used this method.

Comment: `textFieldShouldBeginEditing ` also you need to set

Comment: dont use  `ContentOffset` equal to  `CGPointMake(0, 0)` this is initial `ContentOffset` of scrollView. You need to set `CGPointMake(0, Y-Param)` Y-Param might be some value

Answer (score 0):

You can use **IQkeyboardmanger** third party library for your project, here is the link for that, https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager